# Is there a performance or execution plan difference for wide queries between START and MATCH?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a meaningful difference in terms of how the query is executed between these two?

```
START n=node(*) RETURN n
```

and

```
MATCH n RETURN n
```

For other more selective queries, (e.g. scanning for all nodes with a certain property with a certain value) I could either use a START clause which finds those nodes via an auto_index, or I could match them.   Is there any difference, or is one as good as the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Neo4j 2.0 supports schema indexing for Nodes while the older version supported legacy indexing.

So it depends if you are using Neo4j 2.0 you can directly start with MATCH clause and accompany it with a WHERE on some node attribute which will directly reference the schema indexing.

While if you are using older Neo4j version with auto indexing you would have to use START to use the indexing.

Also you would need to specifically mention the index name and the attribute on which the indexing is done.But in case of MATCH the schema indexing is automatically referred, no need to mention it explicitly.

Also another point to note is that currently schema indexing is not available for relationships but only for nodes. Schema indexing supports only full name searches. Lucene based wild card searches arent supported yet by schema indexing. So again depending on your use case , you would need to make a choice what kind of indexing you would need to use and based on that you can use either START or MATCH.